# If $x \in (b, \infty)$ Show there exists a natural number $n_0$ such that $x > b + \frac{1}{n_0}$

Tags: real-analysis

Assume $\displaystyle \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{n} =0$ and for $b \in \mathbb{R}$, $\displaystyle \lim_{n \to \infty} b = b$. WITHOUT using the Archimedean postulate, show that if $x \in (b, \infty)$, then there exists a natural number $n_0$ such that $x > b + \frac{1}{n_0}$

Can someone please explain to me how I can show it without using the Archimedean postulate, since that is the only way I know how to answer this question ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $x-b>0$ there is $n_1$ such that for $n>n_1$ we have $\left|\frac{1}{n}-0\right|<x-b$. This is the definition of $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n}=0$ particularized for $\epsilon=x-b$.

Therefore $b+\frac{1}{n_0}<x$, for $n_0=n_1+1$.

Comment: So basically, we're using the definition of the limit? :). Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

As x>b and suppose there is natural no. n where :
x <= b + 1/n

So, x-b <= 1/n

Now, 1/n <= 1 (1/n can't be more than 1, it can be only equal and less than 1).

So, x-b <= 1/n <= 1

=> x-b <= 1 for all x.

But as we can see, x can be in the range (b,∞) :
So, what if x>b+1 
than x-b > b+1-b
=> x-b > 1
which contradicts the assumed statement So, there must exist a natural no. n0 where x-b > 1/n0
=> x> b+ 1/n0.

Comment: Thank you! :). Can you please type this in LaTeX? :) . It's a bit hard to read this way, since I am using my cellphone. :)

Comment: The $x$ in the problem is given and therefore fixed. Maybe they gave you an $x>b$ such that $x-b<1$.